# String Variable To Regular Expression Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have a regular expression defined as a string that I want to evaluate against an input string, for example:

```
let myVal = "22.00";
let strReg = "^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$";
let regex = new RegExp(strReg);
if (myVal.match(regex)){
    console.log("It's a valid two decimal place number")
} else {
    console.log("It's invalid")
}
```

If I change the expression to `"^\\d*\\.?\\d{0,2}$"` then it works.

My question is how can I format `strReg` using javascript, so it evaluates correctly. Example code here https://jsfiddle.net/h0795vte/

Comment: You cannot. You need to escape the backslashes in the string literal that you assign to `strReg`, otherwise that string simply won't contain any backslashes in the first place.

Comment: Something like `const strReg = String.raw\`"^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$"\`` might be a good use case here

Comment: @asyncawait Yes, but that's equivalent to writing `const strReg = "^\\d*\\.?\\d{0,2}$"`, which the OP doesn't seem to want to change. They could of course just write `const regex = /^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/`;` in the first place :-)